# What is the "correct" workflow in Apple's ecosystem for sharing/grouping photos?

Tags: mac, iphone, photos

My goals are:

1. Share photos within my group (family/friends/whatever)
2. Not have duplicate photos all over the place (they get out of hand quickly)
3. Be able to work with the photos easily (for example, edit them, select them from standard iOS share dialog in other apps, etc.)

Here's an example scenario: my husband and I go on vacation together for a week and during that time we each shoot 50 photos on our iPhones.

We come home and we want to pool/share our photos. We are fully invested in the Apple ecosystem (both on iPhones and use Macs, we have a family plan for our iCloud storage, etc.).

As far as I know here are our options today:

1. **We each send our photos to each other using normal sharing** (airdrop, messages, email, whatever). Problem: we now both have a full set of 100 duplicate photos on two different phones. Any edits or changes either of us makes is independent from the other person.
2. **We add the photos to a shared iCloud photo album.** Problem: now I have my 50 photos in 2 places (both in my personal photos, and in this shared iCloud album). Also: I can't edit any photos in the shared album; if I want to work with any of my husband's photos, I first have to save them into my personal photos, which means now there are basically 2 copies of that same photo.
3. **We can use some 3rd party app/platform (like Google Photos) that would, presumably, solve all this.** HUGE problem: it doesn't work with the Apple ecosystem; as far as I know there is no third-party solution that integrates with iOS as well as Apple's native photos app. So, for example, if I'm using the Facebook on my phone and want to add a photo, there's no way retrieve a photo from a 3rd party app, only from my Apple photo library. Of course I can pull a photo from this 3rd party place and put a copy in my local photos app to then share to Facebook, but now we're getting into the duplicate photo/etc problem again, not to mention a ton of extra taps.

Am I missing something, or is this the current state of the Apple photo sharing ecosystem? Is there some other way to solve the problem of intelligently sharing/pooling photos?

Comment: I don't think problem #2 is correct.  Adding a photo to a shared album shouldn't make 2 copies of that photo on your device, nor 2 copies eating up your shared iCloud storage.  There will be a copy on each person's device(s), but the original photographer shouldn't have 2 copies.  I hadn't run into the problem with editing shared photos (I guess because I'm usually the photographer and the editor), but that sounds like an Apple-thing, to make the shared photos read-only (to other users) in that album.

Comment: @jimtut I'm afraid it's true. I just tested it: I took a new photo, added it to a shared album, and it appeared in both "my photos" and the shared album (so far so good). Then I deleted it from "my photos" but it was still in the shared album. So maybe the flow is (a) take photos, (b) add them to shared album, (c) delete all those photos from "my photos." BUT then I can't perform any editing on them, even though I am the "original editor" of the pics. Yeah, I think shared albums are "read only" for everyone.

Comment: Back in the "iPhoto" days on your Mac, you could right-click and say "Show in Finder" or something.  I can't find that in Photos, or maybe that's because I'm using the iCloud Photos Library now.  And you can't see anything like that on the phone anyway.  Anyway, what I wonder is if Photos is really keeping 2 copies of the photo, or it's just keeping 2 "references" to it.  That takes a little more coding, but is much more space efficient, and it's definitely what they do for "local" albums - it's a reference to the same photo, not a copy.  Not sure how to tell if they do that for Shared albums.

Comment: Shouldn't family sharing have some extra comfort for such cases? You could also use dropbox or similar and sign in with same account everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment-- Not sure what you mean by "extra comfort." Dropbox is an option but it suffers from all the problems I outline in #3 above. It's also incredibly clunky in general to move files around like that.